# Using map method to find a total?

Tags: javascript

So let's say I have some data.

```
const cart = [
[{name: "Jose", total: 5}],
[{name: "Rich", total: 10}]
]
```

How do I total up those totals using map or forEach?

Comment: `map` isn't appropriate for this job, because it looks at items one at a time, without passing any data between them.  `forEach` could do it, but you'd need to use an extra variable outside.  [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) is the most appropriate method to use for this.

Answer (score 1):

> **How do I total up those totals using map or forEach?**
>
> The function `Array.map()` is to create new arrays applying a specific handler to each element.  On the other hand, the function `Array.forEach()` could be a good approach to loop and sum the values.

The best approach is using the function `reduce`.

Assuming that sample always has an array with one index.

```js
const cart = [[{name: "Jose", total: 5}],[{name: "Rich", total: 10}]],
      total = cart.reduce((a, [{total} = [obj]]) => a + total, 0);
      
console.log(total);
```

Comment: FWIW, I wouldn't use the destructuring syntax because it glosses over that abomination of an input structure that is an array of arrays where each inner array only contains a single object.   Any time a data structure looks like that someone has done something wrong on their design.